# How to permanently set composer env variables in a .env file?

Tags: php, environment-variables, composer-php, dotenv

I'm using PHP composer to deal with env variables and I've set a few in a .env file. Composer recognizes it and adds them to $_ENV just fine.

However, is there a way to keep a synchronous relationship between $_ENV and .env file? This way composer would override the file with updated $_ENV information so I could use it afterwards.

Is it possible? Since $_ENV only keeps the actual variables per session.
I'm asking this because I wanted to keep refreshing an API token in a file. I'd also appreciate if there's some workaround or if I actually didn't understand the concept properly.

**EDIT**

I wanted to setup a .env file so I could access my app's IDs in one place. However, simply creating this file would not make the data contained in it available for me to use in PHP, and that's where composer comes in handy. I'm using the following package (declared in composer.json) that does it for me.

```
"require": {
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.5"
}
```

Of course I could use built in getenv, although I was taught that it was not thread safe.

Comment: Sure, you could write that value back to the .env file if you like, but you'll have to code that yourself, and that opens up a whole new can of worms -- namely, the process reading the .env file generally shouldn't have _write_ access to it. That said, if you have a short-lived API token, you're probably better off storing it in a cache rather than an .env file.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you. I have basically 3 different lines of information. ID and Secret that are constants, and a token that keeps refreshing, so I only would want to keep only the first ones in a .env file, right?

Comment: In general, yes, that's correct. What's the lifetime of the token?

Comment: Alright, 6 hours. I also receive a refresh token I can use to retrieve another valid token after it's expired.

Comment: If it's time or cost prohibitive to generate a new token whenever you need one, you could write it to a cache with a TTL of slightly less than 6 hours. When you need a token, check the cache first, if there's nothing there, generate a new one and put it in the cache.

Comment: @AlexHowansky By cache you mean storing it in a session (or cookie) variable?

Comment: No, I mean a generic cache like Redis or Symfony/Cache or heck even just a text file on the local filesystem.

Comment: @James do not store anything in a cookie that you're not 1000% fine with users being able to see and change.

Comment: Why not use any component that parses the .env file for you, like `symfony/dotenv`? As Composer itself should not be running on your production system, I struggle to understand how this is related?

Comment: I don't know symfony that much, but I might take a look into it. But assuming I'm using pure PHP in a production environment, what would actually be the best or proper way to storage these tokens? I don't have a configured database.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56361460/21636652) elaborates on this matter. My thought is that it'd be safe to store them in a session since they're only available on the server side and I don't really have any other reliable kind of cache other than writing those information in a text file.

Comment: What do you mean by "pure PHP"? How do you use Composer to deal with these variables after all? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm using composer for files autoload and env management. The solution I did was to only set constants to .env (ID and Secret) and only use it to retrieve those. For the OAuth tokens, I'm storing them in a session and it's working just fine.

Comment: @James: Can you please provide reference to what it means using "Composer for env management"? About using "Composer for files autoload" I'd assume you refer to [Autoloading - Basic usage - Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading), right? But for environment management, I have no clue what this is about. Please add all those specifics to your question by [edit]ing it. _"[...]  I've set a few in a .env file. Composer recognizes it and adds them to $_ENV just fine."_ If you could elaborate on and reference how you do this and how Composer does it for you?

Comment: If you are still facing any problem, please add all clarification to your question by editing it. As Composer does not handle something like "env management", please also clarify what you mean by that